# Should exterior receptacles be on a separate circuit from interior receptacles?

Tags: electrical, outdoor, nec

For some reason, I thought I remembered reading in the 2011 or 2014 NEC that exterior receptacles/lights need to be on a separate branch circuit than one powering interior receptacles/lights, but now I cannot find any reference. Am I misremembering?

I plan to run a separate circuit for the exterior receptacles so I can turn them  off when I am not using them, but I would prefer to tap off of interior lighting circuits to power the outdoor lighting fixtures for convenience if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no NEC restriction to keep indoor and outdoor lighting and receptacles separate. I've never even heard this mentioned before.

It's not a bad idea to keep receptacles separate, even for the reason you mentioned, but lighting is no problem to combine. Just keep an eye on the intended use loads so that you will not have a circuit loaded to heavily.